# How to disable Silverlight DataGrid validation footer?

Tags: silverlight, validation, gridview, datagrid, validationsummary

I'm facing the following problem: I'm using validation summary popup for displaying errors on the page, and i have an editable DataGrid. So there are 2 problems:

1) DataGrid validation duplicates validation error, if it occurs in the DataGrid cell. For example. DataGrid contains a collection of objects IEnumerable. When I'm doing ComplexObject.Validate() for each object in collection, i get 1 validation error for each incorrect object in the DataGrid footer and 2 same errors in my Validation Summary popup. I tried with another Datagrid (Telerik) and it worked just fine, so i assume it's DataGrid's problem, though Telerik control doesn't suit me.

2) DataGrid validation foot is redundant, and i want to remove/hide it.

Is there any way to achieve both options at the same time? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the datagrid validation summary (question #2), extract the style using blend or reflector, stick it in a Style resource dict, and remove the validation summary control.

Then reference the style in the datagrid declaration (Style={StaticResource DataGridOverrideStyle}).  Here's the xaml for silverlight 4 if you don't have reflector or blend:

```
<Style TargetType="local:DataGrid" x:Key="DataGridOverrideStyle">
    <Setter Property="RowBackground" Value="#AAEAEFF4" />
    <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="#00FFFFFF" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
    <Setter Property="HeadersVisibility" Value="Column" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Extended" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserResizeColumns" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserSortColumns" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="VisibleWhenSelected" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="DragIndicatorStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <!-- TODO: Change the TargetType to Control when the fix Jolt bugs 18719 is verified -->
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#7FFFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <!-- TODO: Change the TargetType to Control when the fix Jolt bugs 18719 is verified -->
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                            <Grid>
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SortStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Unsorted" />
                                        <VisualState x:Name="SortAscending">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SortIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1.0"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="SortDescending">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SortIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1.0"/>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SortIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).ScaleY" Duration="0" To="-.9"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                                <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundRectangle" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#66808080" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

                                <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradient" Stretch="Fill" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="0" >
                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=".7,0" EndPoint=".7,1">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0.015" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.6" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                </Rectangle>

                                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>

                                    <Path Grid.Column="1" Name="SortIcon" Fill="#7FFFFFFF" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Opacity="0" Stretch="Uniform" Width="8" Margin="4,0,0,0" Data="F1 M -5.215,6.099L 5.215,6.099L 0,0L -5.215,6.099 Z ">
                                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".9" ScaleY=".9" />
                                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                                    </Path>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="DropLocationIndicatorStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF3F4346"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="2"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                            <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="Vertical" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalGridLinesBrush" Value="#FFC9CACA" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalGridLinesBrush" Value="#FFC9CACA" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:DataGrid">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="2">
                        <Grid Name="Root" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <!--Start: TopLeftHeaderTemplate-->
                                <ControlTemplate x:Key="TopLeftHeaderTemplate" TargetType="localprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
                                    <Grid Name="Root">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="#FFC9CACA" Background="#FF1F3B53" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                            <Rectangle Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1">
                                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=".7,0" EndPoint=".7,1">
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FCFFFFFF" Offset="0.015" />
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#F7FFFFFF" Offset="0.375" />
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.6" />
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#D1FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                                            </Rectangle>
                                        </Border>
                                        <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto" StrokeThickness="1" Height="1" Fill="#FFDBDCDC" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                                <!--End: TopLeftHeaderTemplate-->

                                <!--Start: TopRightHeaderTemplate-->
                                <ControlTemplate x:Key="TopRightHeaderTemplate" TargetType="localprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
                                    <Grid Name="RootElement">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Border BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" BorderBrush="#FFC9CACA" Background="#FF1F3B53" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                            <Rectangle Stretch="Fill">
                                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=".7,0" EndPoint=".7,1">
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FCFFFFFF" Offset="0.015" />
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#F7FFFFFF" Offset="0.375" />
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.6" />
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#D1FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                                            </Rectangle>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                                <!--End: TopRightHeaderTemplate-->
                            </Grid.Resources>

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <localprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader Name="TopLeftCornerHeader" Template="{StaticResource TopLeftHeaderTemplate}" Width="22" />
                            <localprimitives:DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter Name="ColumnHeadersPresenter" Grid.Column="1"/>
                            <localprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader Name="TopRightCornerHeader" Grid.Column="2" Template="{StaticResource TopRightHeaderTemplate}" />
                            <Rectangle Name="ColumnHeadersAndRowsSeparator" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto" StrokeThickness="1" Height="1" Fill="#FFC9CACA"/>

                            <localprimitives:DataGridRowsPresenter Name="RowsPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" />
                            <Rectangle Name="BottomRightCorner" Fill="#FFE9EEF4" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" />
                            <Rectangle Name="BottomLeftCorner" Fill="#FFE9EEF4" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                            <ScrollBar Name="VerticalScrollbar" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Width="18" Margin="0,-1,-1,-1"/>

                            <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Rectangle Name="FrozenColumnScrollBarSpacer" />
                                <ScrollBar Name="HorizontalScrollbar" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="18" Margin="-1,0,-1,-1"/>
                            </Grid>

                            <!--<dataInput:ValidationSummary Name="ValidationSummary" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" MaxHeight="0" />-->
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="False" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" CornerRadius="2" Background="#8CFFFFFF" Opacity="0"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to subclass the DataGrid and set the MaxHeight of the ValidationSummary control to zero in the OnApplyTemplate override. Something like this:

```
public class NoValidationSummaryDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        var summaryCtrl = GetTemplateChild("ValidationSummary");
        ((ValidationSummary)summaryCtrl).MaxHeight = 0;
    }
}
```